# request.user for anonymous users or not in django?

Tags: html, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm working in django and got a doubt in the authentication system that, request.user work for anonymous user also or it just work only for the user who have logged in the website.I have read alot of articles but just wanted a clear answer.Also I have a custom user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is *not* logged in, then `request.user` will return the [**`AnonymousUser`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object). It is an object where for example `.is_authenticated` is `False`, the primary key `.pk` is `None`, etc.

If the user is logged in, it will return an object from the model of your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` (by default, this is the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model)).

This thus makes it easy to check for example if a user is logged in with:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # …
    else:
        # …
```

So this will *not* raise an error if the user is not logged in.

You can restrict a view for logged in user with [**`@login_required`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. This will redirect a user to the login view in case the user is not logged in.

Comment: Can we save the AnonymousUser object in our database in the  ForeginKey model field??

Comment: @PrateekGupta: no, an `AnonymousUser` is not a real model. If you call `.save()` then it will rase a `NotImplementedError`. You can thus not use it in a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: So is there any modal field which we can use to save an anonymous user??

Comment: @PrateekGupta: no, usually one stores `None` in that case, since there is no specific user.

Comment: Ok,so if I save an anonymous user in my database and if that user come again to my website then will django recognize that user or not??I know its quite stupid but I just want to clear my doubt

Comment: @PrateekGupta: no, since an `AnonymousUser` means the user is not logged in, if the user comes back, you do not know if that is the same user or not.

Comment: Instead of using the `@login_required` decorator you can use the `LoginRequiredMixin` when working with class based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin